# How do I explode equal length strings into Pandas DataFrame columns (without empty column)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with strings of equal length (10). I want to "explode" this column into 10 columns. No matter what solution I try, there is a leading empty column. Existing solutions give me this problem, so needless to say existing answers to this question are not satisfactory.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['tenletters', 'alsotenten', 'letter10!!', 'ten10lette'], 
    columns=['col1'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['col1'].str.split('').tolist())
```

```
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
0    t  e  n  l  e  t  t  e  r  s   
1    a  l  s  o  t  e  n  t  e  n   
2    l  e  t  t  e  r  1  0  !  !   
3    t  e  n  1  0  l  e  t  t  e
```

How can I do this the proper way (i.e., without a leading empty column)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(df['col1'].apply(list).tolist())
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  t  e  n  l  e  t  t  e  r  s
1  a  l  s  o  t  e  n  t  e  n
2  l  e  t  t  e  r  1  0  !  !
3  t  e  n  1  0  l  e  t  t  e
```

Comment: the `.values` seems redundant

Answer (score 3):

Use `map`

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame(df['col1'].map(list).tolist())

Out[44]:
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  t  e  n  l  e  t  t  e  r  s
1  a  l  s  o  t  e  n  t  e  n
2  l  e  t  t  e  r  1  0  !  !
3  t  e  n  1  0  l  e  t  t  e
```

Answer (score 0):

You use [**`pd.Series.apply`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply)

```
df.col1.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x)))

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  t  e  n  l  e  t  t  e  r  s
1  a  l  s  o  t  e  n  t  e  n
2  l  e  t  t  e  r  1  0  !  !
3  t  e  n  1  0  l  e  t  t  e
```

You can try this for fun. (**Not** a performant solution)

Using [**`pd.Series.str.extractall`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html)

```
df.col1.str.extractall(r'(.)').unstack()

       0
match  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0      t  e  n  l  e  t  t  e  r  s
1      a  l  s  o  t  e  n  t  e  n
2      l  e  t  t  e  r  1  0  !  !
3      t  e  n  1  0  l  e  t  t  e
```

**Note:** The column is `MultiIndex` to make it a single-level `df.columns = d.columns.get_level_values(1)`